# Friedmann equation of motion w.r.t Number of E-folds

Tags: homework-and-exercises, cosmology, cosmological-inflation

So the number of e-folds is given by $N=\ln(a)$ which can act as a substitute for time variable. So I would like to use the fact that $H = \dot{a}/a$ in order to derive the equation of motions for $\phi$, using $N=\ln(a)$ as a time variable. This means that in the differential equation
$$\ddot\phi + 3 H \dot\phi + V'(\phi)=0$$
and
$$3 H^2 M_p^2 = \dots$$

I want the equation to have no time derivatives anymore, but only derivatives with respect to $N$.

Can anyone help me in doing this or point out any papers/resourced which have done this before?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the time derivatives as derivatives with respect to N.  From the definition,
$$a(t) = e^{-N(t)}$$
we have $dN = -d\ln a = -Hdt$.  Now just use this to write $d/dt$ in terms of $d/dN$:
$$\frac{d}{dt} = -H \frac{d}{dN}$$
and
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2} = -H\frac{d}{dN}\left(-H\frac{d}{dN}\right) = H \frac{dH}{dN}\frac{d}{dN} + H^2\frac{d^2}{dN^2}$$